Get address based on Latitude and Longitude Flutter (Using GeoCoding)
so i have used geocoding to get real address based on the geo location(Latitude and Longitude) but it keep giving me errors!
if(permission == LocationPermission.denied || permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  print("location Denied");
  LocationPermission ask = await Geolocator.requestPermission(); 
} else {
  Position currentpossition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  double lat = currentpossition.latitude;
  double long = currentpossition.longitude;
  List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long);
  
  if(placemarks != null && placemarks.isNotEmpty) {
    print(placemarks[0]);
    return placemarks[0];
  } else {
    print("No placemark found for the given coordinates");
    // Handle the case where no placemark is found
  }
}

it gives me this error
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 586:18  nullCheck
packages/geocoding/geocoding.dart 31:33                                           placemarkFromCoordinates
packages/wk01/LocChecker.dart 26:42                                               getCurrentLocation
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 163:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 847:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 876:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 652:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 722:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                <fn>

